# Converting units and currency

Tags: arithmetic

A supermarket in Japan sells soy milk for 398 yen per liter. If there are 83.35 yen per dollar, then what is the price in dollars per quart? 
Conversions that were given.
Dollars per foreign =0.0120  Foreign per dollar 83.35 1 liter= 1.05669

My answer was $5.05 per quart but apparently was wrong.

Comment: It often helps to keep the units with you in your calculations. Here $398 Y/L=398\times(Y/D)\times(Q/L)D/Q=\dots$ with obvious abbreviations.

Comment: So would $4.51 be correct?

Comment: To extend my previous comment, you know that $Y/D=1/83.35$ (since $1D=83.35Y$) and you also know the number $Q/L$. Plug the numbers into the formula and see for yourself.

Comment: Sorry if I'm slow math isn't my forte but thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{398 \text{ yen}}{1 \text{L milk}} \cdot 
\frac{\text{1 dollar}}{83.35 \text{yen}} \cdot
\frac{\text{1 L}}{1.05669 \text{ quarts}} = 
\frac{398}{83.35 \cdot 1.05669} \frac{\text{dollars}}{\text{quart of milk}} = \\4.518870237\dots \frac{\text{dollars}}{\text{quart of milk}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for verifying the answer

Answer (score 0):

1 Liter costs $\frac{398 \ \text{Yen}}{\text{liter}} \cdot \frac{ \ \text{Dollars}}{83.35 \ \text{Yen}}$ The result is in Dollars per liter.

Now you have to convert the liters in quart. 1 quart = 0.946352946 Liters

1 Liter$= \frac{1}{0.946352946}$ quarts.

Thus 1 quart costs in Dollar: $\frac{398 \ \text{Yen}}{\frac{1}{0.946352946} \text{quart}} \cdot \frac{ \ \text{Dollars}}{83.35 \ \text{Yen}}$

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me set it up

Comment: You are welcome. I have more or less the same result. I have $\approx 4.52 \ \text{Dollars/quart}$